# DataNode not starting on any of the nodes

Tags: hadoop

All daemons are starting when I work with pseudo node configuration but any time I make a fully distributed mode cluster, the DataNode daemon does not start on any of the nodes, including the Master node.

What could be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the `namespaceID` is the same for `/tmp/hadoop-hduser/dfs/data/current/VERSION` in all the nodes and `namespaceID` matches for `/tmp/hadoop-hduser/dfs/data/current/VERSION` and `/tmp/hadoop-hduser/dfs/name/current/VERSION` in master.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way how to do this. I hope it helps:
http://www.technology-mania.com/2011/03/hadoop-in-distributed-mode.html
GL!

Answer (score 0):

delete /hadoop-2.6.0/dfs/data before starting the cluster